# can't update images "JLabel setIcon"

Tags: java, swing

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NtNP.jpg)
i want to update the order of the images when i read an array...so i tried to put the destination of the images as variables, then change the variables when i need to change the order but that didn't work.

```
   JLabel no3 = new JLabel();
    no3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(three));
    panel.add(no3);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.validate();

    JLabel no4 = new JLabel();
    no4.setIcon(new ImageIcon(four));
    panel.add(no4);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.validate();


    JLabel no5 = new JLabel();
    no5.setIcon(new ImageIcon(five));
    panel.add(no5);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.validate();
```

when i update the images destination variables "three" "four" and "five" etc, after clicking on another button the images doesn't change....

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Solve");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String text=textField.getText();
            int[] arr = Arrays.stream(text.split(" ")).map(String::trim).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
            int[] solve= new int[9];
            for(int i=0; i<9;i++)
            {
                solve[i]=arr[i];
                 switch (i) {
                    case 0:  one="C:\\Users\\Mostafa\\Downloads\\Compressed\\cut_images_LVx5IFG8ujN\\image_part_00"+solve[i]+".jpg";
                             break;
                    case 1:  two="C:\\Users\\Mostafa\\Downloads\\Compressed\\cut_images_LVx5IFG8ujN\\image_part_00"+solve[i]+".jpg";
                             break;
                    case 2:  three="C:\\Users\\Mostafa\\Downloads\\Compressed\\cut_images_LVx5IFG8ujN\\image_part_00"+solve[i]+".jpg";
                             break;
                    case 3:  four="C:\\Users\\Mostafa\\Downloads\\Compressed\\cut_images_LVx5IFG8ujN\\image_part_00"+solve[i]+".jpg";
                             break;
                    case 4:  five="C:\\Users\\Mostafa\\Downloads\\Compressed\\cut_images_LVx5IFG8ujN\\image_part_00"+solve[i]+".jpg";
                             break;
                    case 5:  six="C:\\Users\\Mostafa\\Downloads\\Compressed\\cut_images_LVx5IFG8ujN\\image_part_00"+solve[i]+".jpg";
                             break;
                    case 6:  seven="C:\\Users\\Mostafa\\Downloads\\Compressed\\cut_images_LVx5IFG8ujN\\image_part_00"+solve[i]+".jpg";
                             break;
                    case 7:  eight="C:\\Users\\Mostafa\\Downloads\\Compressed\\cut_images_LVx5IFG8ujN\\image_part_00"+solve[i]+".jpg";
                             break;
                    default: nine="C:\\Users\\Mostafa\\Downloads\\Compressed\\cut_images_LVx5IFG8ujN\\image_part_00"+solve[i]+".jpg";
                             break;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so i tried to put the destination of the images as variables, then change the variables when i need to change the order but that didn't work.

Of course that doesn't work. The Icon has doesn't know you changed the variable and the label doesn't know you changed the Icon.

So the code should be:

```
//case 0:  one="C:\\Users\\Mostafa\\....";
Icon icon = new ImageIcon("the file name");
no0.setIcon( icon )
```